# How can I exclude a folder from indexing in Sublime Text, while still showing it in the sidebar?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

For a large project with many dependencies e.g. in the `node_modules/` folder, I noticed frequent CPU spikes because of Sublime indexing all the files in the folder.

I know I can hide files and folders using the `folder_exclude_patterns` setting, but I still want the folder to be visible in the sidebar.

How can I keep e.g. `node_modules/` in the sidebar, but exclude it from indexing?

Answer (score 202, accepted):

To exclude files from the index but keep them in the sidebar, use the `binary_file_patterns` setting in your User Settings, for example:

```js
"binary_file_patterns": [
  "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.ttf", "*.tga", "*.dds",
  "*.ico", "*.eot", "*.pdf", "*.swf", "*.jar", "*.zip",
  "node_modules/**",
  "bower_components/**"
]
```

Make sure to copy the values from your `Settings - Default` preferences (here shown as `"*.jpg"` etc.), or you will start indexing binary files.

Comment: I wanted to accomplish the same thing as OP, but for what it's worth, Sublime Text 3 cpu usage spikes for me with "binary_file_patterns." Unfortunately, I can only get it to calm down by using "folder_exclude_patterns." I am on a late 2013 Macbook Pro.

Comment: I've got the same issue as @BrianFitzGerald, have to use folder_exclude_patterns when on OS X. (ST Build 3103, OS X 10.11)

Comment: Works for me in the latest Sublime Text version Build 3126 on OSX El Capitan.

Comment: `To exclude files from the index but keep them in the sidebar...` This is pure genius!

Comment: As of March 2017, the Sublime Text 3 preference is `index_exclude_patterns`, e.g.

`"index_exclude_patterns": ["*.log","node_modules/**","bower_components/**"]`

Comment: @PaulWenzel I just discovered that setting, but when I do a Find in Files, those show up. Is it only for indexing `meta` constructs like function names?

Comment: @Michael I read that `"folder_exclude_patterns": ["name_of_folder"]` might help remove certain patterns from search results, but I haven't tested it. Source: https://coderwall.com/p/bk90bw/exclude-a-directory-from-searching-in-sublime-text-2

Comment: @Michael I can confirm that `index_exclude_patterns` doesn't hide `node_modules`'s files from the "Goto Anything" (⌘P) search:

`"index_exclude_patterns": ["*.log", "node_modules/**"],`

Tested with Sublime Text 3.1.1, Build 3176.

Comment: So far the only working solution has been `binary_file_patterns`.

Comment: Why two asterisks? Also I want to exclude all of a folder except JSON file in that folder. Could you suggest a way for this?

Comment: @Nishant Two asterisks are not actually necessary. `/*` and `*/` are treated as globs.

Answer (score 40):

You can change your personal settings, in `Preferences -> Settings - User`, add:

```
{
    "folder_exclude_patterns":
    [
        ".svn", ".git", ".hg", "CVS",
        "node_modules",
    ],
}
```

Comment: This is not the solution if you still want the folders to show on the sidebar.

Comment: I use this to hide and ignore folders with command-P:
`"folder_exclude_patterns": ["build/**", ".gradle", "node_modules/**"],`

Answer (score 14):

Sublime Text 3 now provides a way to exclude files and folders from indexing while keeping them in the sidebar:

```
  "index_exclude_patterns": [
    "*.log",
    "node_modules/*"
  ]
```

On my project I observed the following improvement in the indexing status menu after applying changes:

Before:

```
index "MyApp" collated in 0.70s from 73934 files
index "MyApp" is using 15167488 bytes for 54234 symbols across 1357673 locations
```

After:

```
index "MyApp" collated in 0.00s from 137 files
index "MyApp" is using 61440 bytes for 730 symbols across 4763 locations
```

Answer (score 6):

Doesn't work in ST3 (Build 3126).

You can show node modules folders in sidebar and hide files inside this way :

```
"file_exclude_patterns":
[
    ...,
    "node_modules/**"
]
```

If you want to hide subfolders from each node module :

```
"folder_exclude_patterns":
[
    "node_modules/*/**"
]
```

All files inside node_modules will be removed from search, but each node_module subfolder will be still visible in sidebar.

Comment: This only shows the node_modules folder but not the sub folder so doesn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

I thought `binary_file_patterns` wasn't working, because I am in the habit of right-clicking my top level folder and choosing "Find in folder". `folder_exclude_patterns` works with this but `binary_file_patterns` still searches everything - because the "Where" field overrides the setting.

So you can either use the menu option Find > Find in files OR right click-your top level folder, choose "Find in folder" and then delete the text in the "Where" field so it shows the placeholder text "Open files and folders".

Obviously you still have to add this to Preferences/Settings:

```js
    "binary_file_patterns": [
      "node_modules/",
    ],
```