# Sublime text performance problems

Tags: sublimetext3, cpu-usage

I have been having performance troubles with Sublime Text 3 for some time. At times I get an "out of application memory" error, and quitting Sublime fixes the problem.

I tried having fewer folders in the project, which helped a bit, but always it comes to the same thing, quitting Sublime and restarting it gives me some respite.

I noticed the problem occurs for a friend running Sublime Text 2, so it's not a newly introduced problem.

I really like Sublime as an editor, and I'm reluctant to consider other tools, but it's not a good situation.

Any ideas?

I'm on Mac OS X Yosemite, build 3126 of ST3, which I updated yesterday.

#### Update:

I found the problem. Thanks to this answer [How can I exclude a folder from indexing in Sublime Text, while still showing it in the sidebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954728/)
Basically I needed to exclude node_modules from the list of files that Sublime watches by adding this to my User Settings:

`"binary_file_patterns": [
    "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.ttf", "*.tga", "*.dds", "*.ico", "*.eot", "*.pdf", "*.swf", "*.jar", "*.zip",
    "node_modules/**",
    "bower_components/**"
]`

My Mac has gone from 75% of the CPU soaked up by Sublime (and being quite hot as a result) to being almost completely idle and cool again. I'm a happy camper now :)

Comment: This might be caused by a plugin — maybe you and your friend both have the same plugin installed. Also, it might be helpful to know what OS you're using.

Comment: Try [reverting to a freshly installed state](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/revert.html) and see if the problem continues. Please also [edit] your question and tell us your operating system and which build of ST3 you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. Thanks to this answer How can I exclude a folder from indexing in Sublime Text, while still showing it in the sidebar? Basically I needed to exclude node_modules from the list of files that Sublime watches by adding this to my User Settings:

```
"binary_file_patterns": [
    "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.ttf", "*.tga", "*.dds", "*.ico", "*.eot", "*.pdf", "*.swf", "*.jar", "*.zip",
    "node_modules/**",
    "bower_components/**"
]
```

My Mac has gone from 75% of the CPU soaked up by Sublime (and being quite hot as a result) to being almost completely idle and cool again. I'm a happy camper now :)