# Ignore node_modules from file search in Sublime 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to ignore anything in node_modules folder when I'm searching for a file name. I tried:

In preferences > package control > package settings > user - settings I included:

```
"folder_exclude_patterns": ["*node_modules*"],
"file_exclude_patterns": ["*node_modules*"],
```

Yet still when I do cmd + p and search for a file Sublime searches in node_modules...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I exclude a folder from indexing in Sublime Text, while still showing it in the sidebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954728/how-can-i-exclude-a-folder-from-indexing-in-sublime-text-while-still-showing-it)

Answer (score 36):

Sublime 3 changes the syntax. You need to remove the wildcard stars.

Go to Preferences > Settings and update the User settings like this:

```
{
    "folder_exclude_patterns": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it in the 'where' field? (e.g. if you don't want to permanently ignore it?)

Comment: @stevec looks like `-*/node_modules/*`